# Pandas dataframe: Sum up rows by date and keep only one row per day without timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have such a dataframe:

```
ds  y
2018-07-25 22:00:00 1
2018-07-25 23:00:00 2
2018-07-26 00:00:00 3
2018-07-26 01:00:00 4
2018-07-26 02:00:00 5
```

What I want to get is a new dataframe which looks like this

```
ds  y
2018-07-25 3
2018-07-26 12
```

I want to get a new dataframe df1  where all the entries of one day are summed up in `y` and I only want to keep one column of this day without a timestamp.

What I did so far is this:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index.date).transform(lambda x: x[:24].sum())
```

24 because I have 24 entries every day (for every hour). I get the correct sum for every day but I also get 24 rows for every day together with the existing timestamps. How can I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need sum all values per days then filtering first 24 rows is not necessary:

```
df1 = df.groupby(df.index.date)['y'].sum().reset_index()
```

Answer (score -1):

Try out:
`df.groupby([df.dt.year, df.dt.month, df.dt.day])['y'].sum()`

Comment: I get an AttributeError: `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'`

Comment: @Tobitor quite a bit old but when we take the example of OP in my opinion it should be ``df["ds"].dt.year``
because Dataframe itself doesn't have the dt attribute, but a column does